# Bean substitute for lamb in moussaka?

Tags: substitutions

I need a recommendation. I have had success substituting beans for meat in a number of baked-bean dishes using spice mixtures from cuisines around the world. I'd like to apply this idea to Greek moussaka, but I can't decide what (dry) bean to use. My gut instinct says, "black beans," but memories of the complete transformation of Navy beans in Boston-style baked beans gives me pause.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A quick google search suggest lentils for vegetarians moussaka.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a while since I've made (vegetarian) moussaka but as Max says in the comments, lentils are a decent substitute here.  I've used Puy lentils or lentilles vert*.  You want something that holds a bit of texture/doesn't fall to bits too easily, unlike red lentils. A mix of red lentils and lentilles vert works well in other things for giving the sauce some body and maintaining texture.  I haven't tried this for moussaka but do use this mixture for lasagne.

For flavour, I'd also add mushrooms, but you don't have to.

Another thing I'd be tempted to try is [urid dal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigna_mungo) (the larger of two things called black lentils) as I have them for making dal makhani.  These would need pre-soaking and longer cooking.

*yes, that is what they're called in my English supermarket; they also sell "green lentils" that are paler and larger.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to remember to report on the results!

Answer (score 5):

Many years ago when I was a vegetarian I used to Swear by Sarah Brown's Vegetarian Kitchen', published by the BBC. Though long out of print, many recipes from it still circulate on the internet. There wasn't a 'moussaka equivalent' recipe, there was a take on Shepherds Pie called Red Dragon Pie whose filling was based on aduki beans. The filling for that became the foundation of many variants whenever I was making a dish that traditionally called for minced meat.

The Complete Wholefood Cuisine by Nikki and David Goldbeck includes a recipe for 'Bean Moussaka' which calls for 'lentils, chick-peas, fava or small white beans'. As I recall I used to use the aduki beans in that recipe.